# How does #{ManagedBean.all} call ManagedBean.getAll()

Tags: jsf, el, getter

I'm not understanding how `<h:dataTable value="#{ManagedBean.all}" /h:dataTable>` results in a function within the `ManagedBean` class `getAll()` being called.

I understand that `<h:form binding="#{ManagedBean.form}" /h:form>` calls the constructor of the `ManagedBean` but not sure how the example above calls a seeming unrelated function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per JSF life cycle, during phase 6 i.e Render response.
"The values to be shown are retrieved from the value binding **getters** in the backing bean. Also If a converter is definied, then the value will be passed through the converter getAsString() method and the result will be shown in the form." . Hence to collection to render in datatable with value="#{ManagedBean.all}", the getAll() method is invoked by JSF.

You can refer below link for more info:

[Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)